# audio.Play() and Destroy (gameObject) timing issue in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, playback, destroy

I've done script for my star to give 1 score point, make particle, play a sound and destroy object. Everything is working fine but now script waits until sound stop playing. What method would you suggest to destroy object before playing sound?
I can make new gameobject audiosource prefab, attach it to star's group and call playback of it like I did with particle system or is there better way to do that?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class Star : MonoBehaviour {

    public ParticleSystem StarParticle;

    public AudioClip otherClip;

    IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter (Collider player)
    { 
        ScoreManager.score += 1;


        StarParticle.Play ();

        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        audio.Play();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(audio.clip.length);

        Destroy (gameObject);

    }
}
```

That's the code.

Comment: well, whats that yield return doing? If you run the script with that line commented out won't that fix your issue? I imagine that would then play the sound, destroy the object without waiting for the sound to complete playback.

Comment: Without yield return game object is destroyed before the sound play because it act very fast. That's my question how to do it without WaitForSeconds to destoy item on trigger enter but let the sound play full lenth

Comment: edit RE: my anwser below: but are you saying that the sound ceases as soon as the object is destoryed?

Answer (score 2):

From reading the comments, how about this:

Take the value of `audio.clip.length` into a variable and reduce it, such as divide by 2 or by 4, etc, so that the script will continue 50% or 25% through the audio file play.

```
 IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter (Collider player)
{ 
    ScoreManager.score += 1;


    StarParticle.Play ();

    AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    waitValue = (audio.clip.length/2);
    audio.Play();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitValue);

    Destroy (gameObject);

    }
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to Unity myself and my syntax is not perfect, re: variable declarations, etc. Sorry.

Comment: Dividing by 2 or 4 is not an option. It cut your audio in half

Comment: hmm, not the time period the audio is played but just the value, so if the audio file is 4seconds then the value is 2 seconds so the game process waits 2 seconds, after the audio begins, before destroying the object. I would be surprised if removal of the object also cuts the related audio unless the audio is a child or component of the object? In which case make the audio a separate object?

Comment: and does this help? http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-can-i-make-a-c-method-wait-a-number-of-seconds.61011/

Comment: That's why I did waitforseconds. If audio source is element of a object it gets destroyed with him.

Comment: You didn't make thet association clear in the question, I will update my answer....

Answer (score 1):

That's solution of my problem. 
I disable collider (to not allow other ppl to get points from that star) and mesh (to make star invisible) and then after playback I destroy my star gameObject. Thx for replies!

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Star : MonoBehaviour {

```
public ParticleSystem StarParticle;

IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter (Collider player)
{ 
    ScoreManager.score += 1;


    StarParticle.Play ();

    AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    audio.Play();
    GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
    GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(audio.clip.length);

    Destroy (gameObject);

}
```

}